# Hide pdf toolbar in firefox while displaying pdf using iframe

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, toolbar, acrobat

I am displaying a pdf file in browser using iframe. It is working fine but i want to disable/hide acrobat toolbar(below image).

[image: Toolbar in firefox]

I tried the solution `#toolbar=0&statusbar=0` it's working great on chrome but it's not working on Firefox. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this...?

Comment: Hello, did you get any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers handle PDF Open Parameters differently (if at all). It is not possible with Javascript to force browsers to support PDF Open Parameters if the browser vendor did not build an API for it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching, there is an answer here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1119523 from user jscher2000 (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/jscher2000)

```
#outerContainer #mainContainer div.toolbar {
  display: none !important; /* hide PDF viewer toolbar */
}
#outerContainer #mainContainer #viewerContainer {
  top: 0 !important; /* move doc up into empty bar space */
}
```

Comment: This is not CSS you can add to your page. It has to be added to the `userContent.css` file of the browser